# Printing loop values to cells with step size less than 1

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to print out the values of each loop iteration when the step size is 1. Is there a way I can do the same with smaller step sizes? The code below is what I have been using when the step size is 1

```
For i = 1 To Height - 1
    Moment = ((Load * i) / (3 * (Height ^ 2)) * ((Height ^ 2) - (i ^ 2)))
    Application.Calculate
    Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value = i
    Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value = Moment
Next i
```

Comment: When using fractional steps, you might want to consider http://stackoverflow.com/q/29558276/11683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this could be flagged as "easily google-able" but you can modify the the for loop with `step [increment]`:

```
 dim k as int    
 k = 1
 For i = 1 To Height - 1 step 0.1
     Moment = ((Load * i) / (3 * (Height ^ 2)) * ((Height ^ 2) - (i ^ 2)))
     Application.Calculate
     Sheet2.Range("A" & k).Value = i
     Sheet2.Range("B" & k).Value = Moment
     k = k + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare `i` as `double`

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is just what I needed. I am still pretty new to VBA so this saved me a lot of frustration!